# WPF: apply style only to one tabcontrol containing other tabControl

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles, tabcontrol

In my wpf application,   I have a tabControl (parent) that contains another tabcontrol (child).
I would like to apply a style to the tabItem of the parent tabControl without affecting the child one.
I tried with this:

```
<TabControl x:Name="Parent" TabStripPlacement="Left" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ParentTabItems, Mode=OneWay}" >
    <TabControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                        <!-- template is defined here-->
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabPanel}">
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        </Style>
    </TabControl.Resources>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentPresenter>
                <ContentPresenter.Content>
                    <!--Here there is the child TabControl-->
                </ContentPresenter.Content>
            </ContentPresenter>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

But this results in applying the style also to the child tabControl TabItem.
How can I apply the style only to the parent tabItem leaving the child TabControl using the default style defined in the application?

Comment: Have you tried simply declaring your style in the parent window resources and using an x:Key on the style?

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for your answer. I would like to use the x:Key but I don't know how to apply this to the TabItem of the tabControl. I tried by setting the style directly to the TabControl but this result in an invalid target object (in the style I target a tabItem not a tabControl)

Comment: I'll look into a solution.

Comment: The only thing I can see that's feasible is to declare another style in the child tab control's resources, this should override the parent style. Possibly not a very elegant solution.

Comment: I already explored this solution, but I would like to inherit the application default style from the child without copy and paste it in the control's resources. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the `TabControl.ItemContainerStyle` to set a named `Style` on the `TabItem`s of the outer `TabControl`. Try this:

In `Resources`:

```
<Style x:Key="ItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <!-- template is defined here-->
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

...

```
<TabControl x:Name="Parent" TabStripPlacement="Left" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ParentTabItems, Mode=OneWay}" 
    ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ItemStyle}">
    <TabControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabPanel}">
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        </Style>
    </TabControl.Resources>
</TabControl>
```

Comment: The **ItemStyle** style wouldn't be resolved in this case, it's inside the TabControl's resources. Did you mean to put the style outside of the TabControl?

Comment: Thanks Sheridan! It works. The only change that I have done is to move the Style definition in the Resources of the containing UserControl\Windows. Otherwise I get an undefined Resource "ItemStyle".

Comment: The edited version is ok! I didn't notice your changes. Thanks again