# How to apply TabControl style to a specific tabcontrol?

Tags: wpf, xaml, tabcontrol, wpf-style

I've a `TabControl` with `TabControl.Resources` defined at the beginning. This is working nicely but the problem is that I've another TabControl inside the parent `TabControl`, and I don't want the style to be applied to the child `TabControl`.

Here's an example:

```
<TabControl>
   <TabControl.Resources>
       some style and triggers
   </TabControl.Resources>
   <TabItem> 
      //Style correctly applied here - there is an external control with a tab item
   </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

The external control is created by me, I simply split the xaml in other file, this has another TabControl and I don't the style of the parent tab to be applied there.

What's the solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF: apply style only to one tabcontrol containing other tabControl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28945115/wpf-apply-style-only-to-one-tabcontrol-containing-other-tabcontrol)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Your problem:

> The problem is that your style has no `x:Key`

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"        
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"        
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <TabControl>
        <TabControl.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"></Setter>
            </Style>
        </TabControl.Resources>
        <TabItem Header="Tab 01">
            //Style correctly applied 
    here there is an external control with a tab item
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Tab 02">//Style correctly applied 
    here there is an external control with a tab item
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

[image]

---

### The solution:

> To avoid a Style from being applied to all Controls of the same type
>   definded in `TargetType` you need to provide a `ResouceKey`.
>
> To apply the Style with an `x:Key` you now need to specify it in the `Style` property of the control you want to use it on.
>
> This is done with: `Style="{StaticResource StyleName}"`

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"        
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"        
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <TabControl>
        <TabControl.Resources>
            <Style x:Key="CustomStyle" TargetType="TabItem">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"></Setter>
            </Style>
        </TabControl.Resources>
        <TabItem Header="Tab 01">
            //No Style will be applied
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Tab 02" Style="{StaticResource CustomStyle}">//Style correctly applied 
    here there is an external control with a tab item
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

This will only apply the `Style` to `TabItem`s where you have set the Style.

[image: StyleApplied]

Answer (score 2):

Like below code:

```
<TabControl>
    <TabControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TabItem" x:Key="tabItemStyle">                
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="Styled Header" />
        </Style>
    </TabControl.Resources>
    <TabItem Style="{StaticResource tabItemStyle}">

    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Simple Header">

    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

***OUTPUT:***

[image: output]